# Failing to add a bibtex file into a main tex file

Tags: bibtex

I see several entries in the forum suggesting that the enclosed Miminal code should print the references in the file `myref.bib` in the tex file here. The output of this file for me gives a pdf file with just the "How are you" written on the entire page.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}

How are you 
\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{myref.bib}

\end{document}
```

The file `myref.bib` is in the same directory and has 3 few entries in the following way:

```
@article{diamondprop,
    author = {Kania D R, Landstrass M I and Plano M A},
    title = {Diamond radiation detectors},
    journal = {Diamond and Related Material},
    year = { 1993 },
    volume = {2},
    number = {1012–9}
}
```

Comment: there are no references in the body of the file. Add `\nocite{*}` and the rerun `pdflatex bibtex pdflatex pdflatex`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing `bibiliography{myref.bib}` write just `bibiliography{myref}` and with one more change in the .bib file it works fine.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

 How are you \cite{diamondprop}


 \bibliography{myref}
 \bibliographystyle{plain}

 \end{document}
```

I also modified the .bib file. Added `add`between the first author and second author's name, ideally you are supposed to do this between every author's name. This is the .bib file I used

```
@article{diamondprop,
author = {Kania, D. R. and Landstrass, M. I. and Plano, M. A.},
title = {Diamond radiation detectors},
journal = {Diamond and Related Material},
year = { 1993 },
volume = {2},
number = {1012–9}
}
```

[image: Output]

This link might be helpful if you are new to this: [Using BIBTeX to create a Bibliography](http://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/help/faqs/latex/bibtex)

I forgot to mention you need to compile it four times in the following order: pdflatex,bibtex,pdflatex,pdflatex.